# BLACKLOTUS UEFI virus: windows cannot avoid but how about Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, malware

Windows is facing a serious threat but what about Ubuntu? Is there any way to avoid UEFI in the boot process or not be affected by BLACKLOTUS?

https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2023/03/blacklotus-malware-hijacks-windows-secure-boot-process.html
https://www.darkrelay.com/post/windows-11-s-secure-boot-defeated-by-blacklotus-malware-cve-2022-21894

Comment: Black Lotus is a Windows-specific problem that takes advantage of unpatched systems. If you would like to avoid being affected by Black Lotus, the simplest method would be to air gap your system(s). If this is not feasible, set your system's language to an Eastern European language, such as Russian, Romanian, Ukrainian, Armenian, or Belarusian. Running Linux is an option but, if you are using Windows in a VM or in a multi-boot configuration, it is still possible to be affected by this virus if you are in the target audience for it.

Comment: Interesting thanks. But if we boot directly under Linux, Black Lotus still a problem for Linux?

Comment: You can use https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/  to look up CVEs for Ubuntu, thus isn't a Linux Q&A site but a Ubuntu site.

Comment: @matigo how can you be affected if you are running Windows in a VM? At worst that would affect the UEFI of the VM not of your own machine, right?

Comment: @guiverc the main question here, for us, is "are Ubuntu systems vulnerable to BLACKLOTUS" and that seems like a useful question to answer. Ubuntu runs Linux, after all, so I don't understand why you would suggest that this is off topic.